# File in git repo becomes inaccessible

Tags: git, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am sharing my git directory (where I keep all my git repos) between my win 10 workstation and a Linux VM running on VMWare Workstation. After a while of working with it, the script I'm working with (called aws_utils.sh) becomes inaccessible.

I just saved some changes to a file, committed and pushed them. Then I switch branches. And I see this message:

```
 git checkout update_aws_list_rds
error: unable to create file aws_utils.sh: Permission denied
Switched to branch 'update_aws_list_rds'
D       aws_utils.sh
```

I did NOT delete this file. It's my main file and I would not do that.

I then take a look at the permissions of that file and they look like this (under linux):

```
-????????? ? ?       ?       ?            ? aws_utils.sh
```

And I can't do anything with the file:

```
ls -lh aws_utils.sh 
ls: cannot access 'aws_utils.sh': Permission denied
```

Even as root, I am unable to even list the file:

```
ls -lh aws_utils.sh 
ls: cannot access 'aws_utils.sh': Permission denied
whoami
root
```

And then a few minutes later the file is just GONE as if I had deleted it. And doing a git pull does not restore the file.

I have to literally delete the directory and clone it again to get the file back.

I check in the update_aws_list_rds branch and the file that was gone before I deleted the directory is there after I clone the directory again.

I am using git version 2.17.1 and VMware player 15.

What is going on that could cause this? How can I stop this problem from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> I am sharing my git directory (where I keep all my git repos) between my win 10 workstation and a Linux VM running on VMWare Workstation.

is almost certainly the problem.

This kind of shared storage never works right.<sup>1</sup>  It plays particularly poorly with Git, which insists on being in full, complete, 100% control over its `.git` directories.  There are two rules of thumb for using Git this way:

1. Don't do it.
2. If you must do it, make sure you do it 100% read-only from at least one side.

Since Git already has *its own* sharing protocol, it's pretty easy to set up a VMWare or VirtualBox system so that the host and client are just two different machines, with two different Git repositories, that use `git push` and/or `git pull` to transfers objects between them.  That way each Git can be in full, complete, 100% control over its own `.git` and the corresponding work-tree, and that *does* work fine.

---

What, never?
Well, hardly ever!

Comment: Ok thanks. I just stopped using my shared storage for this purpose. I wasn't actually sharing just the git folder. I was sharing a parent folder that had a lot of other stuff I share, the git directory happened to be there. 

I just moved the git folder out of there to a local folder both on the windows machine and the linux vm. That should solve the issue.

Comment: I have a similar setup on my Mac with a Linux VM, and it's really quite annoying since MacOS and Linux should be able to play better together than Windows and Linux. I use some shared folders for occasional file transfer but for reliability I have to keep almost all of the Linux-side data in the non-shared area.